# Finding specfic jsp page and extenting functionality using hook

Tags: liferay

I am using liferay. I want to add new functionality to existing jsp page.
I will be using hooks for that purpose.
The problem is how to find existing jsp pages locations?

For example
I want to locate "Add regular Organization" page.
Pls help

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsp files under source folder : `html\portlet\users_admin\organization` and `html\portlet\users_admin\edit_organization.jsp` are jsps for "Add regular Organization" page.

There are certain ways, liferay provides its functionalities using default portlets that comes with liferay-bundle. You can look at folder `portal-web\docroot\html\portlet` under `portal-src`, it will give you idea to locate jsp page locations.

Moreover you can look at `portal-web\docroot\WEB-INF\portlet-custom.xml`, `portal-web\docroot\WEB-INF\struts-config.xml` and `portal-web\docroot\WEB-INF\tiles-defs.xml` for portlet specific actions and respective jsps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.U answer on liferay forums as well as stackoverflow.

Comment: where can i find this portal-web or portal-src?